# Google is making a change to DMARC that affects Salesforce

Tags: security, singleemailmessage, goole-dmarc-security

If you took a looked into [Salesforce-Outbound-Emails-Impacted-by-Google-DMARC-Policy](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Salesforce-Outbound-Emails-Impacted-by-Google-DMARC-Policy-Adoption&language=en_US)

I understood we can't use other gmail address to send email from salesforce instance.

So as per my understanding if we just set the from address in single email message then this  Google DMARC-Policy security will not effect.

So basically we need to use organisation wide address to set the from address in single email message. This way we can solve this issue.

My idea is using organisation wide address because this security will effect only those email which are generated from @gmail.com domain.

If we use @ourcompanyAddress.com then issue may resolved.

Can anyone confirm if my understanding is correct or any other steps that we need to follow for Google DMARC-Policy security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think your interpretation is correct. Nothing in the article you linked suggests that using an `Organization-Wide Email Address` will circumvent the policy. There are two steps you need to take, based on the documentation you linked to:

- you need to register for a domain that you control, and use this new domain for all of your emails sent from Salesforce
- refrain from sending any email through our service from any domain that you do not control

> **2. What action do I need to take?**
>
> To prepare for this change, **you need to register for a domain that you control, and use this new domain for all of your emails sent from Salesforce**. Review the Changing user email addresses help article for more details on how to make the update.
> ...
> To ensure the delivery of your emails, you should **refrain from sending any email through our service from any domain that you do not control**, including but not limited to other major service providers domains such as Gmail, Outlook.com, and more.  To date, Yahoo, AOL and Google have or will implement this strict email policy, and other domain owners will likely do so in the future.

Comment: any idea where we need to register our domain ?

Comment: @ratan That is a question probably more suited to [so]. It doesn't really have anything to do with Salesforce. There are a wide variety of domain providers available. You will need to do your own research to determine which is the best fit for you.

Comment: Perhaps you will find [this](http://web.appstorm.net/roundups/email-roundups/the-best-places-to-host-your-email-with-your-own-domain/) helpful. I do recommend you do your own research though.